# RegionPlot fails when given function with internally redefined variables

Tags: functions, version-10, plotting

I've just upgraded to v10, and have noticed that some of my trusty old notebooks which used `RegionPlot` now fail to run. I've boiled down the problem I'm having to the following examples.

This first example works fine. This function outputs the value of a paraboloid polynomial:

```
parabolloid = Function[{input1, input2},
 x = input1;
 y = input2;
 x^2 + y^2
]
```

Suppose I want to plot the region for which the function output is <1:

```
RegionPlot[parabolloid[x, y] < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

Result is as expected:

[image: Result]

Now let's rewrite the function like so, swapping where I write the exponent:

```
parabolloid = Function[{input1, input2},
 x = input1^2;
 y = input2;
 x + y^2
]
```

This ought to give us identical results. First, let's test the function:

```
parabolloid[2, 2]
```

The returned value is 8, as expected. So the function still seems to work a-ok.

But when I evaluate the function in RegionPlot as above, my CPU churns away for a few seconds before getting a beep with kernal quit.  No error messages or warnings, just a Kernel quit.

Surely we ought to be able to perform operations on input arguments within a function, and on v8, that seemed to work fine.  (Admittedly, I don't have v8 handy at the moment, so I can't test my simple examples above, so I suppose I can't prove without doubt that this is a version-specific issue)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: As far as I can see, everything runs as it should if you use a more compact definition of your functions, for example parabolloid = Function[{x, y}, x + y^2]. Otherwise localize the x and y in your definition: parabolloid = Function[{input1, input2}, Module[{x, y}, x = input1^2; y = input2; x + y^2]]

Comment: I think first you should try localizing your `x` and `y`.

Comment: Right you are Silvia and Fred, it was a localization issue.  Rewriting the RegionPlot syntax as the following did the trick:
    RegionPlot[parabolloid[x1,y1],{x1,0,2},{y1,0,2}] 
I can only guess that it worked in the first example I gave because the x = input1; y = input2; lines didn't actually change the values of x and y from their assignments given by RegionPlot.

Comment: Works fine with me without problems. try to quit MMA and start again.

Comment: I can reproduce the crash in a fresh kernel on v10.0.1 Windows 7 64-bit.  The plot is created successfully on versions v7.0.1, v8.0.1 and v9.0.1 on the same machine (despite the unlocalized use of `x` and `y`).

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the crash on V10.0.1 Mac OSX 10.9.5.

```
parabolloid =
 Function[{input1, input2},
  x = input1^2;
  y = input2;
  x + y^2];
```

This crashes the kernel (uncomment or copy without the comment markers if you wish to run):

```
(*
RegionPlot[parabolloid[x, y] < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
*)
```

Note the function is not well-defined:

```
parabolloid[x, y]
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

```
(*  Hold[x^2]  *)
```

Still, a more graceful way of letting the user know that *Mathematica* is dissatisfied than crashing is desirable.  You should report it to WRI.

Another source of "dissatisfaction" by *Mathematica* may be that `RegionPlot` is trying to control the values of `x` and `y` and `parabolloid` is resetting them.  This is not good practice even if it works on some versions of *Mathematica*.  (It would be nice if *Mathematica* would warn you when you try do it.)  Workarounds, involving localizing `x` and `y` in `parabolloid`, are offered in the comments.